# Validate ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using C# with the Entity Framework Model and Oracle. 
When I want to add a value then it gives me this error.

Of course I know what the problem is: When inserting or updating records, a numeric value was entered that exceeded the precision defined for the column.

But now I want to ask how I can validate this. I want to check if a value will match with the precision of a column.

The precision of the column should not be given, it should be read from the database so I can use it universal for all of my tables.

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please redefine your question to point the problem how to check the size as is not related to oracle error.

Comment: You could use a `DESCRIBE table` like function to get to know what the length of the column is.

Comment: When using an ORM, you should not be able to get these errors as the ORM (Entity Framework in this case) should know what value type you are using and create columns of the appropriate type and size accordingy. Are you using the Entity Framework to define your database?

Comment: No I'm not using the Entity Framework to define my database. I've a ready database and created a entity framework model from this ready database. I will test it with the DESCRIBE table command! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when Error ORA-01438 happens, It mean that there is a fault in the database table column design (if the data is correct), it is not able to contain the data.

So you should not to check the precision of a column but ask the designer to modify the design.